# What can I do with less than 5000 expiring Hilton Honors points?

Tags: hotels, loyalty-programs, expired, hilton

I have a couple of thousand Hilton Honors points expiring in July.  I virtually never stay in Hiltons and have no plans to do so before or after July, so I'd prefer to just clear out my balance and be done with it.

Poking around the HHonors site, the [cheapest award redemptions](https://www.hilton.com/en/hilton-honors/points-explorer/?cid=OH,HH,PointsExplorerStayActiveLP,MULTIPR,Tile,Booking,Book,i86695) start from 5000 points, while [transfers to mileage programs](https://www.thepointcalculator.com/us/hotel/hilton/hilton-transfer-partners) require 10,000.  So far, I've identified exactly three things I could do:

- <s>Redeem a "Points & Money" rate for a Hilton room, not useful since I don't stay in Hiltons</s> (not an option, minimum spend 5,000 points)
- Use them for [shopping on Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089G92XVF) at a rate of 500 points per USD (laughably terrible value at 0.002c/point)
- Transfer them to family or friends who do use HHonors; this seems like the least bad option so far?

Any other ideas?  And yes, I'm aware this is a low-stakes question since HHonors point are typically valued around 0.5c each, meaning we're talking about <$25 here.

Comment: You can donate them to a charity of your choice using Pointworthy (min 3500 points)
 https://www.pointworthy.com/partners/hilton/

Comment: There's a few options listed on https://www.headforpoints.com/2023/12/30/how-to-use-small-amounts-of-hotel-points/